# LaTex Awesome CV - indented subentry?

Tags: overleaf, awesome-cv

i am in a rotational program and i want to separate my singular position into 3 subgroups (each with their own bullet points) under work experience as shown in this photo. [image]

i haven't the slightest idea how to do this in awesome-cv. doesn't matter how hacky it is!

the template is found here: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm
and i haven't made any changes to the awesome-cv.cls file.

made the edits @whatisit posted below. gave the following output:
[image]

only slight changes i'd like to see to this- how do i make the rotation headings be styled the same as the the other position titles (where it says "associate" & "intern"), and finally, i still want the default bullets as shown under the second company, instead of dashes.

Comment: Can you clarify:  under a specific company/position within Work Experience?  Or on the same level as a company/position?  And do you want to retain the standard task items, in addition to this rotational information?

Comment: You have been taken in by a common misconception.  What is referred to on the internet as “LaTeX templates” are in reality **other people's documents** which are tailored to their *specific* needs.  Therefore it is close to **impossible to perform any modifications** on these without breaking the entire thing.  They are really only meant to exchange their content with yours.  Any other adjustment is simply out of scope.

Comment: Ok, as I mentioned in the answer, you can remove `[]` (i.e. `\item[]` becomes `\item`) to keep the bullets.  I used `[]` because your original image didn't have them :-)

Comment: As for the styling, let me clarify.  You want "Business Analyst Rotation" and "Rotation" to have the same formatting as "Associate" and "Intern", in the second image?

Comment: ^upon doing that- the "Rotation" becomes bulleted, and nothing else changes. i want the "rotation task 1, rotation task 2, rotation task 3" to be bulleted and not dashes, and yes, you are correct regards the styling. thanks!

Comment: Gotcha.  I misunderstood which list items you were referring to.  I'll include that with the formatting update.

Comment: @jake I believe I covered the changes you were looking for.  Check my edit answer and let me know if I missed or misunderstood anything.

Comment: @whatisit, wonderful work man, thank you so much! could you check my other question i posted and see if you can solve that problem as well? thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility, if you want to retain the general style in the `cventries` is to just put a `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}` block inside and remove the bullets from the `cventries` `item`s

In the `experience.tex` file, replace everything between and including the `\begin{cventries}...\end{cventries}` stuff with this:

```
\begin{cventries}
%---------------------------------------------------------
  \cventry
    {Rotational Program Associate} % Job title
    {Some Corp.} % Organization
    {City, Country} % Location
    {Jan. 2016 - PRESENT} % Date(s)
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
        \item[] {1st rotation
            \begin{itemize} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
                \item {rotation task 1}
                \item {rotation task 2}
                \item {rotation task 3}
              \end{itemize}}
        \item[] {2nd rotation
            \begin{itemize} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
                \item {rotation task 1}
                \item {rotation task 2}
                \item {rotation task 3}
              \end{itemize}}
        \item[] {3rd rotation
            \begin{itemize} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
                \item {rotation task 1}
                \item {rotation task 2}
                \item {rotation task 3}
              \end{itemize}}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
%---------------------------------------------------------
\end{cventries}
```

The `\item[]` removes bullets from those items.  Remove `[]` if you want bullets again.

The result looks like this:
[image: Remove bullets and add embedded itemize list tasks in Awesome CV]

**VERSION 2:**

The job position is wrapped in `\entrypositionstyle{...}`, as defined by the awesome-cv.cls.  So, you can wrap the sub-position titles inside of it.  For example, `\entrypositionstyle{1st rotation}` in the original answer or `\entrypositionstyle{Business Analyst Rotation}` in the OP edit.

If you prefer something easier to remember, you could `\let\jobstyle\entrypositionstyle` in the preamble (i.e. above `\begin{document}` in `resume.tex`).  Then, use `\jobstyle{Business Analyst Rotation}` instead.

The bullet issue is because you are two levels deep, instead of only one level deep.  Before the job/tasks list, you can `\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\bullet}` to force the second level to have bullets also, instead of dashes.

The updates look like this.  I kept the third job/task without the formatting to provide comparison.

**resume.tex**

```
...
\let\jobstyle\entrypositionstyle
...
\begin{document}
...
```

**experience.tex**

```
...
\begin{cventries}
%---------------------------------------------------------
  \cventry
    {Rotational Program Associate} % Job title
    {Some Corp.} % Organization
    {City, Country} % Location
    {Jan. 2016 - PRESENT} % Date(s)
    {\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\bullet}
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
        \item[] {\jobstyle{1st rotation} %VERSION ONE (requires resume.tex change)
            \begin{itemize} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
                \item {rotation task 1}
                \item {rotation task 2}
                \item {rotation task 3}
              \end{itemize}}
        \item[] {\entrypositionstyle{2nd rotation} %VERSION ONE (does NOT require resume.tex change)
            \begin{itemize} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
                \item {rotation task 1}
                \item {rotation task 2}
                \item {rotation task 3}
              \end{itemize}}
        \item[] {3rd rotation
            \begin{itemize} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
                \item {rotation task 1}
                \item {rotation task 2}
                \item {rotation task 3}
              \end{itemize}}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
%---------------------------------------------------------
\end{cventries}
...
```

Result looks like this:
[image: Updated version with level 2 bullets and job position formatting]

Note that `\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\bullet}` in the location that I place it will not affect other second-level bullets.  If you want *all* second-level bullets to change for the entire resume, move `\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\bullet}` to `resume.tex` above `\begin{document}`.

Comment: this is almost perfect, thank you! i edited my initial question to show a photo of what that fix did. only slight changes i'd like to see- how do i make the rotation headings be styled the same as the the other position titles (where it says "associate" & "intern"), and finally, i still want the default bullets as shown under the second company, instead of dashes. thanks! @whatisit

Comment: 100% perfect. thats for the update and detailed explanation. it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i'm sorry @whatisit but i've been thinking, i think i would prefer for the subbullets (rotation task 1, rotation task 2, rotation task 3) to be aligned with "1st rotation, 2nd rotation, 3rd rotation" i would like to keep the actual bullet points, just remove the slight indentation so its aligned. how would i go about this?

Comment: @jake I'm not sure you'll be happy with this...it looks very "busy".  But this method also allows you to increase/decrease the indent, so here goes.  Replace `\begin{itemize}` with `\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]`.  If you want to play around with the indent, replace `leftmargin=*` with a specific dimension (e.g. `2pt`, `-1em`, `0.5ex`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

> doesn't matter how hacky it is!

That is exactly the spirit you need when dealing with LaTeX “template” garbage found on the internet.  Let's get to it.

Open `awesome-cv.cls` and find the definition of the `cventries` environment.  Replace it with this.

```
% Define an environment for cventry
\newenvironment{cventries}[1][0pt]{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \begin{center}
  \leftskip=#1\relax
}{%
  \end{center}
}
```

Then open `experience.tex` and find the `cventries` environment after the `\cvsection{Work Experience}` heading.  Add an optional argument with the amount of indent you like, like below.

```
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTENT
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{cventries}[20pt]

%---------------------------------------------------------
```

Enjoy your fork number
[image]
 of Awesome CV.

[Live example on Overleaf](https://v1.overleaf.com/read/jysjwqgcsgvf)